# CSS on all nodes?

Tags: html, css

I have inherited the following HTML (which cannot be changed) and have been tasked to CSS a hover so all of them have a new background color and the text is white. I cannot get all of them to change and the text to be white when hover. Can anyone advise what the correct CSS would be?

**CSS that DOES NOT WORK**

```
ul.dynamic:hover > li.dynamic:hover > a.dynamic:hover >span.additional-background:hover > span.menu-item-text:hover;
ul.dynamic > li.dynamic > a.dynamic > span.additional-background > span.menu-item-text:hover
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dynamic">
    <li class="dynamic">
        <a class="dynamic">
            <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item-text">
                    HomePage
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What element specifically are you trying to change the `color` and `background-color` of?

Comment: All of them. I want the UL, the LI, the A, the SPAN to all have a new background color and the only text (in the SPAN) to have the forecolor as white.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this

```
ul.dynamic:hover > li.dynamic:hover > a.dynamic:hover > span.additional-background:hover > span.menu-item-text:hover
{
    background:red;
    color:white;
}
```

You can also add other properties whatever you want to change.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xh7N9/)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried exactly what you have and they all do not have the background color nor change font color.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say because you aren't specifying which element's CSS needs to change.  I am going to assume that the `background-color` of `span.additional-background` needs to change and the text `color` of the `span.menu-item-text` needs to change, in which case it would look like this:

```
ul.dynamic > li.dynamic > a.dynamic:hover > span.additional-background {
    background-color: #333;
}

ul.dynamic > li.dynamic > a.dynamic:hover > span.additional-background > span.menu-item-text {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Both of those are unnecessarily specific, but I am assuming they need to be in order to overwrite whatever existing CSS there is that you didn't show us.  Really the first selector could just be `a.dynamic:hover > span` and the second could be `a.dynamic:hover > span > span`.

Comment: Thank you. We need all of the elements to change background color and the only text to change foreground color. I copied this into my CSS and it is still not working. I will continue to research.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the CSS code that sets the properties of these elements? It's relevant as we need to ensure the styles we provide are specific enough to override the old styles on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Semicolon(;)` to combine two styles.

Try to make css style separating the selectors with a comma :

```
ul.dynamic:hover > li.dynamic:hover > a.dynamic:hover >span.additional-background:hover > span.menu-item-text:hover,
ul.dynamic > li.dynamic > a.dynamic > span.additional-background > span.menu-item-text:hover
```

[In jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xh7N9/1/)

Comment: Thank you. That was mearly a typo on my part. In the actual code, it is only separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

We finally got our style to look the way we wanted to on this. We ended up having to start at a higher node and (for whatever reason) had to include both of the following lines:

```
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox:hover li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-navedit-linkNode:hover,
li.static > ul.static > li.static > a.static > span.additional-background:hover > span.menu-item-text:hover
```

Thank you everyone for your assistance!